# Adding a second rewrite rule in .htacces doesn't work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to .htaccess so this might seem an obvious question
I have the following rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Category\.php\?Category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ Category.php?Category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I would like to add a similar rule to a product page like so:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However when these two are in the .htaccess file it doesn't work Only the first rule will work the second rule will give an error.
Thanks for looking

Comment: @Ria: I left a comment on your other question. When you enter `/foo` it can be either forwarded to `Category.php` OR `product.php` but not to both. You will need some prefix before category or product URI like `/p-abc` for products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to elaborate further, you can have rules this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Category\.php\?Category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/p/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/p/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ Category.php?Category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If I use this the page displays wrong and the url is: my page.co.uk/34 product name/p/ Thanks again

Comment: It seems it works but you just have css issue as you're not getting 404 error right?

Comment: If have change it slightly to:RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /p/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/p/([^/]+)?$ product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
 It now gives me a 404 page not found error

Comment: Yes because you have `RewriteRule ^/p/` instead of `RewriteRule ^p/`

Comment: I removed the / however now the page is coming up but all the formatting is gone. The p/ is not a valid directory it is just to make it different from the Category redirect. That was what I was hoping for.

Comment: That is css issue since you're using relative links. just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
OR  You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help AGAIN. I've changed to the absolute paths and it worked. Thank you

Comment: I have some more problems I will start a new question. Sorry to keep hassling you. I changed the Category to look like this my site/C/Category name the problem is now that when I call for the product page from the category page it cannot find it as it is calling it in mysite/C/product.php etc.

Comment: Ok sure let me know the link when you create the new question.